# Page Jerk on Jquery.load() Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am using Jquery.load(html) function to load some html in a div. My code look like below.

```
$("#preview-content").load("abc/abc.html", function(){
$('#workPhone').text('0123456');
//...and some more text fields fill here
}
```

when this code execute whole page gets a jerk. it looks like all page is refreshing while in actual just one div is loading. I have changed the .load() function with ajax call like below.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "abc/abc.html",
  dataType: 'html',
  success: function(html) {
  $("#preview-content").html(html);
  return false;
  }
});
```

and this is showing the same result. navigation, toolbar, grid, everthing get a jerk like its reloaded. Any idea what i am doing wrong?

Comment: can you share us a fiddle of your work?

Comment: sorry! its not possible as i am working on SPA and it has a lot of code dependent. The thing is if i remove the load function and paste the html in place then it work fine. if i use load function then it starts splashing and giving an effect that page is reloading.

Comment: well you are resetting the contents of the element, if the element does not have a fixed width/height its going to resize with the content, which will cause the other relative elements to move around as it does so. You can gradually hide the element before putting the new content in and then gradually show it after the new content has been placed, (jQuery's slideUp, slideDown for example) so there isnt a jerking motion.

Comment: Yes this trick helped. Thanks a lot Patrick. Please place your code in answers so i can vote it...

Comment: @StrugglingUser you could try to load a real website like [google](http://www.google.com) or something so you can still do the fiddle

Comment: @ejay_francisco that would be so hard. anyhow i will do some RnD on this as well that how can i place the fiddle from my portion of application. Thanks a lot.